# Host Card Emulation on Nexus 7 2012

Tags: nfc, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, hce

I'm trying to test out the new Host Card Emulation features in KitKat, but the only KitKat device with NFC that I have at the moment is a 2012 Nexus 7. It does support card emulation through Google Wallet, and I can send and receive data to the two Master Card AIDs that it uses.

However, when I try to implement my own `HostApduService` to handle communications with my own custom AID, Android doesn't route any APDUs to my service. I then tried to call `CardEmulation.isDefaultServiceForAid` to see if my service is the one that should handle my custom AIDs. When I include the `CardEmulation` class in my code, the application crashes.

Looking at `logcat`, there's an entry that says "this device does not support card emulation." Is there a reason why the 2012 Nexus 7 does not support this? It has all the necessary hardware and does emulate cards when using Google Wallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Card emulation for Google Wallet on the Nexus 7 (2012) is done using an embedded "Secure Element" (essentially a smart card chip). However, the NFC controller on that Nexus 7, unfortunately, does not support HCE under Android 4.4 Kitkat.

Comment: Is this a software/driver issue or a hardware issue? It seems to me it must be a software/driver issue since NXP chip supports CE. Google Wallet claims to support Tap and Pay. So this sounds like a bug, no?

Comment: The specific way that Google has combined CE in the Secure Element and HCE by apps, using routing based on the selected AID, requires support from the NFC controller to be able to implement this. The NFC controller in the Nexus 7 (2012) cannot provide this.

Comment: Sorry to highjack a thread - but is there some list of devices that *do* support it? I also have a 2012 N7 and thinking that it had NFC and 4.4, it would work. What about Samsung galaxy s4 mini? (does not yet have 4.4, but still). I'd get a N5 but I like a smaller form factor...

Comment: I am not aware of such a list.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237583/list-of-devices-support-hce