# List of devices support HCE?

Tags: nfc, host, android-4.4-kitkat, emulation, hce

As more and more devices have KitKat, I'm trying to compile a list of devices support HCE.

Does anyone have the list? Feel free to add comments to contribute to this list.

Below is what I have so far:

### Notes:

- Not all KitKat devices support HCE.
- To detect HCE support, use this code snippet:

  ```
  boolean isHceSupported =
      getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.nfc.hce");
  ```
- Some people reported that KitKat HCE phones has "Tap & Pay" in NFC Setting. I don't know if using "Tap & Pay" as HCE detection method is valid because "Tap & Pay" can mean Tap & Pay using internal SE. It doesn't have to be HCE.
- Phones with Broadcom NFC controller will support HCE.
- Phones with NXP NFC controller may/may not support HCE.
- Or use [this Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inoapp.cardinfo) to detect HCE & NFC controller type.

### Support HCE:

- Sprint Note 3 (Broadcom)
- Sprint Galaxy S 4
- Nexus 5
- Nexus 7 (2013)
- Moto X ([source](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/11/19/how-to-get-google-wallet-tap-pay-working-on-the-moto-x-with-kit-kat/))

### Do not support HCE:

- T-Mobile Galaxy Note 3 (NXP)
- AT&T Galaxy Note 3
- Nexus 7 (2012)

Comment: To add the the Not Supported list:HTC Evo 4G LTE

Comment: A list of smartphones and their NFC chipset: http://www.shop4nfc.com/blog/a-comprehensive-list-of-nfc-enabled-phones/

Answer (score 5):

> I beleive All handsets with Android Kitkat, having NFC, supports HCE.

Based on above, [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sName=&idMaker=0&idAvailability=0&YearAnnounced=0&nPriceLow=0&nPriceHigh=0&idCurrency=0&idFormFactor=0&idSIMType=0&idDualSIM=0&idQwerty=0&HeightMax=0&WidthMax=0&ThicknessMax=0&WeightMax=0&idOS=0&idOSVersion=0&idOSWhen=0&nminCPUMHz=0&nCPUCores=0&nminRAMMB=0&nminInternalStorageMB=0&idExpansionCard=0&idDisplay=0&nminDisplayX=0&nminDisplayY=0&nmaxDisplayX=0&nmaxDisplayY=0&fminDisplaySize=0&fmaxDisplaySize=0&nPixelDensity=0&idDisplayTech=0&idTouchscreen=0&idAccelerometer=0&idGyro=0&idCompass=0&id35mm=0&idCamera=0&idCameraFlash=0&idVideoRecorder=0&idSecondaryCamera=0&idGPS=0&idWLAN=0&idNFC=1&bEDGE=0&bGPRS=0&idBluetooth=0&bIR=0&bEmail=0&bWAP=0&bJava=0&idRadio=0&bMMS=0&idRingtones=0&sColor=&nBatteryCapacity=0&StandBy=0&TalkTime=0&sFreeText=Kitkat) is the list returned by [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/) - currently 77 handsets.

```
Top 70 out of 77
---------------------------
Samsung Galaxy S5   
LG G3   
Sony Xperia Z2   
Samsung Galaxy Note 3   
Samsung I9500 Galaxy S4   
HTC Desire 816   
HTC One (M8)   
Sony Xperia T3   
Sony Xperia Z   
Sony Xperia M2   
LG Nexus 5   
Samsung I9190 Galaxy S4 mini   
Motorola Moto X   
Sony Xperia Z1   
LG G2   
Sony Xperia T2 Ultra   
Samsung Galaxy Note II N7100   
HTC One   
Sony Xperia SP   
Huawei Ascend P7   
Samsung Galaxy S5 Active   
Sony Xperia Z1 Compact   
Sony Xperia Z Ultra   
HTC One mini 2  
Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 I9200   
LG Nexus 4 E960   
Sony Xperia ZR   
Samsung Galaxy K zoom  
Samsung I9505 Galaxy S4  
LG G Pro 2  
OnePlus One  
Sony Xperia ZL  
Vertu Signature Touch  
Samsung Galaxy S5 mini  
LG Optimus G E975  
Samsung Galaxy S5 (octa-core)  
Samsung Galaxy S5 G9009D  
Asus Google Nexus 7 (2013)  
Samsung I9305 Galaxy S III  
Asus Google Nexus 7  
Lenovo Vibe Z2 Pro  
Samsung Galaxy Ace Style  
LG G2 mini LTE  
Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet LTE  
HTC Butterfly  
LG L70 D320N  
Samsung Galaxy J  
Asus Memo Pad 8 ME581CL  
BLU Vivo IV  
HTC Butterfly S  
LG Optimus L9 II   
HTC One (M8) CDMA   
LG Volt   
Motorola DROID Ultra   
HTC One M8 Prime   
Asus PadFone S   
Motorola DROID Maxx   
LG G2 mini LTE (Tegra)   
Sony Xperia Tablet Z LTE   
BLU Life Pure XL   
Motorola RAZR i XT890   
Samsung Galaxy S5 CDMA   
LG F70 D315   
Motorola RAZR HD XT925   
Motorola DROID Mini   
Sony Xperia Z2 Tablet Wi-Fi   
Samsung Google Nexus 10 P8110   
Alcatel Idol 2 S   
LG Lucid 3 VS876   
Alcatel Idol 2 Mini S
```

Comment: I have a Samsung Note 3 and I can verify that HCE, while possible, is not turned on in my phone.  The chip manufacturers' have just released an updated driver that will turn on support, but that driver won't be installed until sometime after the next Samsung update. (Running on AT&T 4.4.2)

Answer (score 3):

I added the following line to my Android Manifest and uploaded an APK to the Play Store to see what devices the Play Store says supports HCE:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true"/>`

The list I received back is below. Note that the Play Store says the Galaxy Note 3 does support HCE, but after testing it, the Note 3 does not support HCE. I think this will be the best way to make a list of devices that support HCE.

```
COOLPAD
 Coolpad 9970L
 Coolpad 8971
 VodafoneSmart4
GOOGLE
 Nexus 10– manta
 Nexus 5– hammerhead
 Nexus 7– flo
 Nexus 4– mako
 Nexus 7– deb
HTC
 HTC6435LVW– dlx
 HTC Desire 601– zaracl
 HTCOneMaxVZW– t6wl
 HTC One– m7wls
 Butterfly S– dlxpul
 HTC One– m7
 HTC 802t– m7cdtu
 HTC6525LVW– htc_m8wl
 HTC One max– t6ul
 HTC_0P9C2– htc_a5ul
 HTC 9060– m7cdug
 HTC Desire 601– zara
 HTC One max– t6whl
 HTC one (M8)– htc_m8
 HTC One– m7wlv
 HTC One dual 802d– m7cdwg
LG
 LG Optimus LTE3– fx1sk
 Optimus GK– gvfhd
 G Pro2– b1w
 LG G2– g2
 LG G Flex– zee
 LG Optimus G Pro– geefhd
 LG Optimus G– geehrc
 G Pro2– b1
 VU3– vu3
 LG Optimus L9II– l9ii
 LG Optimus G Pro– geefhd4g
 G2 MINI– g2m
 LG Gx– omega L70– w5n
 LG Optimus G– geehrc4g
MOTOROLA
 Droid Ultra– obake
 Moto X– ghost
 Droid Mini– obakem
 Droid MAXX– obake-maxx
PANTECH
 VEGA Secret IP– ef62l
 VEGA Secret UP– ef61k
 VEGA Secret UP– ef60s
SAMSUNG
 Galaxy S4– jflteaio
 Galaxy S4– jflteusc
 Galaxy S4– jfltecsp
 Galaxy S3– d2vzw
 Galaxy S5– kwifi
 Galaxy S5– k3g
 Galaxy S4 Mini– serranolteusc
 Galaxy Note2– t0lteusc
 Galaxy S4– jfltecri
 Galaxy S4– jftdd
 Galaxy S4– jalteskt
 Galaxy S4– ks01ltelgt
 Galaxy S4– jfvelte
 Galaxy S4– jflte
 Galaxy Note2– t0ltektt
 Galaxy S4– jflteatt
 Galaxy S4– jfltespr
 Galaxy S5– kltelra
 Galaxy S5– klteMetroPCS
 Galaxy S5– klteskt
 Galaxy Note3– hlteskt
 Galaxy S3– d2usc
 Galaxy S4– ks01lte
 Galaxy S4 Duos– ja3gchnduos
 Galaxy Note2– t0ltelgt
 Galaxy S4– ja3gduosctc
 Galaxy S5– klteatt
 Galaxy S4 Active– jactivelte
 Galaxy Note3 Neo– frescoltelgt
 Galaxy S4– jfltevzw
 Galaxy S4– ja3g
 Galaxy Note2– t03g
 Galaxy S4 Mini– serranoltespr
 Galaxy S4– jfltecan
 Galaxy Note3– hltespr
 Galaxy Note2– t0lte
 Galaxy S5– kltetmo
 Galaxy S4– ks01lteskt
 Galaxy Note3– hltelgt
 Galaxy Note2– t0ltespr
 Galaxy S5– klteusc
 Samsung Galaxy S4– jflteMetroPCS
 Galaxy S4– jaltektt
 Galaxy S4 Google Play Edition– jgedlte
 Galaxy Note3– ha3g
 Galaxy S4– jfltetmo
 Galaxy S4 Mini– serranoltevzw
 Galaxy S5– kltelgt
 Galaxy S4 Active– jactivelteatt
 Galaxy S4– jflterefreshspr
 Galaxy Note3– hltektt
 Galaxy S5– kltektt
 Galaxy Mega 6.3– meliusltespr
 Galaxy S3– d2vmu
 Galaxy S3– d2spr
 Galaxy S5– kltevzw
 Galaxy S4– jaltelgt
 Galaxy S4– jfltelra
 Galaxy S4– ks01ltektt
 Galaxy S5– klte
 Galaxy Note3– hlte
 Galaxy Note2– t0lteskt
 Galaxy S5– kltespr
SONY
 Xperia Z1– C6903
 Xperia Z2 Tablet– SGP511
 Xperia Z2 Tablet– SGP512
 Xperia Z2– D6502
 Xperia Z1– C6906
 Xperia Z2– D6503
 Xperia Z1– C6902
 Xperia Z2 Tablet– SGP521
 Xperia Z Ultra– C6833
 Xperia Z1– C6943
 Xperia Z Ultra– C6806
 Xperia Z1 Compact– D5503
UNKNOWN
 jfltexx
 htc_m8whl
 kltecan
 mx3
 x5
 htc_m7
 w7n
```

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 does not support HCE

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted some manufactures: 
 
- All devices from htc with nfc and Android >= 4.4 support HCE (I tested the HTC One M8). 
 
- From Motorola only the Moto X support HCE.
 
- LG doesn't have a list but the LG G2 support HCE. 
 
- The statement from Samsung is not jet available.

Answer (score 0):

List of device with Android 4.4

```
Samsung Galaxy Note 2
Samsung Galaxy Note 3
Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0
Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (todas las versiones)
Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 Edición 2014
Sony Xperia Z
Sony Xperia ZL
Sony Xperia ZR
Sony Xperia Z1
Sony Xperia Z Ultra
Sony Xperia Z Tablet
LG G2
LG T Pad 8,3
LG T Pro
LG VU 3
LG Optimus 4X HD
HTC One
HTC One Max
HTC One X
Asus Fonepad Notes 6
Asus Fonepad 7
Asus Padfone Infinity
Oppo Find 5
Oppo N1
Huawei Ascend P6
Huawei Ascend G700
Motorola Moto X
Motorola Moto G
```

Comment: As for Samsung Galaxy Note 3, T-Mobile version doesn't support HCE as I listed in the question.

Comment: Samsung mobile spain on twitter said update to Android 4.4 [link](https://twitter.com/SamsungMobileES/status/442974901709058048)

Comment: If a phone gets KitKat 4.4 update, it doesn't mean that it will get HCE. 
Also the phone variant matters, could you put the variant in your list?

Comment: I added the following line to the Android Manifest to require HCE.
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true"/>`
After exporting and building an APK, I uploaded it to the Play Store, and in the supported devices list I saw that the Note 3 supported HCE (even though after testing, it clearly does not support HCE).

Comment: @aguy What Note 3 variant do you have ?
Use the code below is better:  boolean isHceSupported = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.nfc.hce");

Comment: Samsung split the supply contract for the NFC chipset in the Galaxy Note 3 between NXP and Broadcom. You may see variances in compatibility because of this.

Answer (score 0):

i think any device without official kitkat support doesn't support HCE because of lack of vendor support, so installing cyanogenmod kitkat doesn't make it HCE compatible

Source: my HTC One X doesn't support HCE on CM ("this device does not support card emulation" in logcat when launching "tap & pay" by force because it's not in menu)