# Is Host Card Emulation (HCE) supported in all 4.4 devices with NFC hardware?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

Can I expect that all devices that come with NFC hardware and Android 4.4 support HCE with features  detailed at android documentation ( ISO/IEC 7816-4  with Type A).

Or at least can I expect that from major flagship phones from major manufactures like Samsung, LG, Sony,...

If it's nor workin in all 4.4 phones with NFC hardware a list of confirmed ones that it works, or an indication of it work in most one them ore only some ones will be apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all KitKat devices with NFC support HCE.
For example, Sprint Galaxy Note 3 supports HCE; T-Mobile Galaxy Note 3 does not.

I'm trying to compile the exact list you mentioned here: 
[List of devices support HCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237583/list-of-devices-support-hce)

Answer (score 1):

Not all Android 4.4 devices with NFC supports HCE. If the device has an option in the Settings for "Tap & Pay", most likely it has an HCE support.