# Smartphone NFC function desktop application

Tags: java, android, nfc, smartphone

It's possible for me to develop desktop application using JAVA that can directly read / write NFC tags using my smartphone? Without using reader such as ACR122u.

In other word, I use my android smartphone as NFC reader connecting with USB cable to my desktop application, read information on passport.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer data to PC from android device via NFC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096356/transfer-data-to-pc-from-android-device-via-nfc)

Comment: @MocialovBoris not really a duplicate as the question you linked asks on how to transfer data between a smartphone and an NFC reader connected to a desktop device over NFC (while this question asks how to use a smartphone in place of an NFC reader with a desktop device).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRoland. This is what I mean, MocialovBoris.

Comment: I see no reason why it should be possible. For the USB aspect you may read this thread:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803871/android-apps-communicating-with-a-device-plugged-in-the-usb-port)