# Transfer data from NFC tag to PC and vice versa

Tags: android, tags, nfc

My concern is somewhat like this: [Transfer data to PC from android device via NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096356/transfer-data-to-pc-from-android-device-via-nfc)

A patient fills up information in the hospital PC/server. After filling up the form, the system will generate a specific ID number to be then inserted to the NFC tag. If for instance the patient comes to the hospital again, he will just present his tag to be scanned and the information needed by the medical staff is supplied.

Any suggestion on how I can make this possible? Any hardware device needed to be connected to my PC to read NFC tags?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to write specific ID? Every NFC tag has its unique ID. You can identify patient with this ID in NFC tag and store neccessary information on server-side.