# HCE: Why can I get fail return code in Sony Xperia ZL?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I have a problem with HCE. I downloaded a sample code from https://github.com/grundid/host-card-emulation-sample. I build it and put it in google Nexus 5. I send the APDU to select AID and it returns successful return code. But I can't get successful return code when I put the same APP in Sony Xperia ZL. If I send APDU FFCA0000 to the two phones, they send back the UID. Can anyone tell me why I can't get successful return code when I send Select AID to the Sony Xperia ZL?

Comment: `FFCA0000` is not an APDU that is sent *to the phone*. Instead this APDU triggers the *card reader* to return the UID of a detected contactless card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Sony Xperia ZL uses NXPs NFC chipset (according to [this list](http://www.shop4nfc.com/blog/a-comprehensive-list-of-nfc-enabled-phones/)). Current<sup>1</sup> HCE capabilities require<sup>2</sup> a device with Broadcom's NFC chipset.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22237583/2425802).

Note that even for non-HCE Android devices a contactless smartcard reader will typically detect the phone as a contactless card. In those cases the reader either detects the phone's secure element or the phone's peer-to-peer mode capabilities.

---

<sup>1</sup>) With current I refer to Android 4.4.2 AOSP, which is the last version where I checked the source code.

<sup>2</sup>) Unless the device manufacturer (Sony in this case) added additional functionality that's not part of AOSP. But I doubt that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find someone can be successful to use this sample on Sony Xperia Z2. I find the phone use the NXP PN544. So I think that the phone can work fine in HCE with new NXP's chip.

Comment: The Z2 contains NXP's PN547 (and not the PN544) which seems to use the NCI stack and therefore does support HCE (see [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_sony_shinano-common/blob/cm-11.0/proprietary-files.txt#L329).